# Async code is stopping after executing a method but it should continue

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm *trying* to create a server that listens for requests to get market prices, gets them and then posts them to a queue to log. My problem seems to be that my program just stops (and pausing execution doesn't show its waiting anywhere and no dispose methods are being called either (breakpoints don't get hit). Its stopping despite there been 70 or so messages to log in the queue.

I guess I could post messages to a message queue and then have a different microservice read them all off but this is bugging me now! Any ideas are welcomed!

I'm pretty sure, somehow the logging loop is being killed after about 500 milliseconds after the "done" call

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        bool sent = false;
        _textLogger.Information(nameof(PriceEngineServer), $"Started {nameof(PriceEngineServer)}");
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        
         while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             if (_price.Connect().Result)
             {
                  if (!sent)
                     {
                         _textLogger.Information(nameof(PriceEngineServer), $"Started requesting prices");

                         IBHistoricalRequest IBReq1 = new IBHistoricalRequest("MSFT", SecTypeEnum.STK, "SMART", "USD",
                             PriceFrequency.Daily, new DateTime(2024, 1, 1), "Trades");
                          _price.RequestPrice(IBReq1);
                          
                          IBHistoricalRequest IBReq2 = new IBHistoricalRequest("AAPL", SecTypeEnum.STK, "SMART", "USD",
                              PriceFrequency.Daily, new DateTime(2024, 1, 1), "Trades");
                         
                          _price.RequestPrice(IBReq2);

                         Console.WriteLine(
                             $"Done {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss.fffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}");
                   //Stops pretty much after this call is made
                         sent = true;
                     }
                 }
              
        }

        _textLogger.Information(nameof(PriceEngineServer),$"Stopped {nameof(PriceEngineServer)}");

    }
```

This is my logging code which I'm DI as a Singleton in to the various classes as required:

```
 public TextLogger(IOptions<LoggerConfiguration> loggingConfig) : base()
{
    _loggerConfiguration = loggingConfig.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggingConfig));
    if (_loggerConfiguration.LoggerType != LoggerType.Text)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(TextLogger)} doesn't match LoggerType of {_loggerConfiguration.LoggerType}");
    }

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string logDirectory = Path.Combine(_loggerConfiguration.TextLoggerConfig.Directory,
        $"{now:yyyy-MM-dd}");

    string uniqueLogName = $"{_loggerConfiguration.TextLoggerConfig.FileName} - {now:HH_mm_ss}";
    string baseLogName = Path.ChangeExtension(uniqueLogName, _loggerConfiguration.TextLoggerConfig.FileExtension);

    string filePath = Path.Combine(logDirectory, baseLogName);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logDirectory);

    //backgroundTask = Task.Run(() => LogAsync(filePath, _logQueue, _tokenSource.Token));
   // Console.WriteLine($"ThreadID {backgroundTask.Status}");
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() => { LogAsync(filePath, _logQueue, _tokenSource.Token); });
    backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
    backgroundThread.Start();
```

}

```
private static async Task LogAsync(string filePath, BufferBlock<LogInformation> logQueue, CancellationToken token)
{
    await using var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
    await using var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var logItem = await logQueue.ReceiveAsync(token);
            Console.WriteLine($"{logQueue.Count} items in the queue");
            string formattedMessage = formatMessage(logItem);
            Console.WriteLine(formattedMessage);
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(formattedMessage);
            //Console.WriteLine($"{formattedMessage} Done");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Out of loop");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Exited Text Logger");
}
```

I've tried adding Thread.Sleep but thats still not logging all the messages in the queue. I've tried exploring this with Chat-GPT but she's none the wiser !

Comment: If locking the `WriteLineAsync` thread is required then this may not work. But instead of using `await` to await the thread and guarantee safety, you could try a fire and forget method and use `_ = sw.WriteLineAsync`. Not sure on your requirements.

Comment: Also curious how you are trying to exit the while loop?

Comment: `_price.Connect()` is async? Never use `.Result`!

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong. I want my logging process to just monitor a queue and write the messages to a file for as long as the program is running.

So to answer @jaabh I'm not trying to exit, should I?

Comment: I would think that exiting the while loop and allowing the thread to be freed up after it writes would be necessary. And for every message in the queue to simply call the function that logs. So exiting the while loop after the write is complete seems necessary. Unless I misunderstand. I would exiting the function after completion is required.